# How could the Riemann Hypothesis be independent of ZFC?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, model-theory

I have read: [Can the Riemann hypothesis be undecidable? from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79685/can-the-riemann-hypothesis-be-undecidable), and [If the Riemann Hypothesis were independent of ZFC, would this mean that $\sigma(n)\leq H_n+e^{H_n} \log(H_n)$  is also independent of ZFC? But how could such an inequality be independent of ZFC? Wouldn’t that just imply that it is true (because no counterproof can exist)? from Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-the-Riemann-Hypothesis-were-independent-of-ZFC-would-this-mean-that-sigma-n-leq-H_n-e-H_n-log-H_n-is-also-independent-of-ZFC-But-how-could-such-an-inequality-be-independent-of-ZFC-Wouldn-t-that-just-imply-that-it). The Quora answer (to the best of my understanding) tells me that supposing we have a stronger system than ZFC (abbr. "SS") in which we prove that the Riemann Hypothesis ("RH") is independent of ZFC, then this is a proof of RH in SS because if RH was false in SS, then there would be a counterexample to Robin's inequality, which would be detectable in ZFC (because Robin's inequality is just simple arithmetic), i.e. RH would be provably false in ZFC, contradicting our assumption that "there is a proof in SS that RH is independent of ZFC".

Is this understanding correct? It's just that I see the statement "Riemann hypothesis may be true but unprovable in ZFC", but have always been confused about it (true with respect to what system? unprovable w.r.t. what system?). Would a better formulation be: "RH may be unprovable in (i.e. independent of) ZFC (with respect to a stronger system SS), in which case the RH is true (i.e. provable) in SS; however in this case there will also be another stronger system SS2 (stronger than ZFC) such that RH is provably false in SS2 (because that is what being independent of ZFC means)"?

EDIT: but in this latter case, wouldn't a proof of the falsity of RH in SS2 translate to a counterexample in ZFC (which would again violate that we proved RH was independent of ZFC in SS, right?)? Unless SS2 is "non-constructive" in such a way that we could proof that RH is false in SS2 without ever being able to get a counterexample. I'm not sure how that would work.

Thanks for any further clarifications.

Comment: "True but unprovable" means "true in the standard model, but unprovable in the theory." A similar example is Golbach's  Conjecture. If you could establish that Golbach's Conjecture is formally undecidable in ZFC, you would also be proving that it is true *in the standard model* for the natural numbers, since if it were false one could exhibit a counterexample and verify it within ZFC. But there would be models in which the meaning of "number" is different, and in which the conjecture might be false. Similar with RH: if it were formally undecidable, it would be true  in the standard model.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: am I right in thinking that you are appealing to Robin's result? So that $\lnot RH$ implies the existence of a natural number $n$ which fails to satisfy an effectively computable predicate. Or is your argument more general than that?

Comment: @RobArthan: A little more general, informed by a general understanding that if a counterexample to RH existed, this fact could be computably verified (though I do not know of a specific theorem stating this precisely).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry for coming back to this so late, but if we can reason rigorously with a particular "standard model", why even bother with a theory that can produce "non-standard" models?

Comment: @D.R. Huh? A model is an *interpretation*. You don't reason "with" interpretations. Reasoning happens in the theory. It's like asking why read books that allow different movie adaptations.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin well if something can be "true in the standard model" like you write in your comment, but "unprovable in the theory", why can't we define a theory that matches exactly with the "standard model"? In your book/movie analogy, if we have the "standard movie", why can't we write a book that produces exactly that movie (such that any other substantially different movie would contradict the book in some way)?

Comment: @D.R. Per Goedel, it is impossible to define a useful theory (one in which you can actually tell whether something is an axiom or not) and which is large enough to include arithmetic, which does not allow for multiple models and for sentences that are true in some models and false in others. That is precisely the content of the Incompeteness theorems.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so humans somehow have this "intuition" for a "standard model", but this "standard model" can not be completely codified in mathematical language?

Comment: @D.R. The standard model exists. It's not an "intuition". But you cannot axiomatize a theory that uniquely characterizes the standard model of arithmetic in a way that (i) you can decide whether a particular sentence is an axiom or not; and (ii) you can model the rules of inference with finitistic methods; think Turing machines. Again, this is the basic content of Goedel's first incompleteness theorem. Rather than ask naive questions in an extended comment thread about it, why not learn those basic facts?

Comment: @D.R. You can easily define a theory that does: just take the theory whose axioms are precisely those sentences which are true in the standard model. The problem is that it is not **useful**. How do you tell if something like Goldbach's conjecture is an axiom or not?

Answer (score 1):

I believe (but cannot find a source for this - someone help me out?) that the Riemann Hypothesis can be translated into a first-order statement about natural numbers.

That is, one can form a statement $P$ using only first-order logic and the fumction symbols $0$, $s$, $+$, and $\cdot$ which is logically equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis in the sense that ZFC proves $\mathbb{N} \models P$ iff the Riemann Hypothesis is true.

Most mathematicians tend to agree that when you make a first-order statement about the natural numbers using only the symbols $0$, $s$, $+$, and $\cdot$, the statement has a "real meaning". That is, each such statement is "really" true or false when talking about the "real" natural numbers.

The truth value of the Riemann Hypothesis is, in a certain sense, meaningful.

But we can go even further. If I recall correctly, the statement $P$ is logically equivalent to a statement of the form $\forall n (f(n) = 0)$, where $f$ is a primitive recursive function. This means that if the Riemann Hypothesis is true in any model of $ZFC$, then $P$ is true in that model of $ZFC$. And this means that in this model of $ZFC$, the statement $\forall n (f(n) = 0)$ is true.

But consider some "actual natural number" $k$. Then in this model of $ZFC$, $f(k) = 0$. But we can calculate $f(k)$ ourselves, so our calculation must give us that $f(k) = 0$. That means that for all "actual numbers" $k$, $f(k) = 0$.

So if $P$ is true in any model of ZFC, it must be a true statement about "the real natural numbers". And therefore the Riemann Hypothesis must "really be true".

Comment: >I believe (but cannot find a source for this - someone help me out?) that the Riemann Hypothesis can be translated into a first-order statement about natural numbers: 


https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence#comment71649_31870

Comment: @ℋolo Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: When you say "real" natural numbers do you just mean the set $\mathbb{N}$? If the statement must be true for that set then does not ZFC prove it by your argument?